# Automated email sending failure in Android

Tags: android, email, jakarta-mail

By following all the steps mentioned in this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-ap/2033124#2033124); I am able to send emails programmatically from my android device using **gmail** credentials. But as soon as I switch to a third party **SMTP** provider (provided by my ISP), the program starts to throw the following exception:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: cp-10.webhostbox.net, port: 465;
 nested exception is:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1391)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:310)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:169)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:118)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:188)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
at com.**.oms.utils.GMailSender.sendMail(GMailSender.java:66)
at com.**.oms.NewUserSignUp$1.run(NewUserSignUp.java:58)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:409)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.<init>(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:661)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.getInputStream(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:632)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.initStreams(SMTPTransport.java:1449)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1366)
... 12 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:282)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:202)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:611)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)
... 16 more
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
... 21 more
```

Below mentioned is the set of properties that I am setting (including the one to accept all the certificates):

```
Properties props = new Properties();   
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");   
        props.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);   
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.checkserveridentity", false);
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "*");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",   
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");   
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");
```

As you can see I am already accepting all the certificates, still am getting this certificate error. Can someone please explain this behavior and the solution to the same.

Answer (score 0):

First, [get rid of all the socket factory stuff](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

What version of JavaMail are you using?  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?  If you're using an old version of JavaMail, it doesn't support the properties you're setting and you might need to use [this approach](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#installcert).